# git instaweb gives 403 Forbidden - No projects found

Tags: git, http-status-code-403, instaweb

running `git instaweb` in my repository opens a page that says "403 Forbidden - No projects found". What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

looks like the debian install of git sets `$projectroot` globally in a way that confuses `instaweb`. I removed the `$projectroot` line from `/etc/gitweb.conf` and the error went away.

Comment: @jes5199's fix also works with Ubuntu (9.04), I guess because debian is upstream.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Git about Git, but you're probably missing the ability to execute on the directory in question,   **chmod +X** it.

Comment: I tried it just to be sure, but it doesn't appear to be correct in this case: `git instaweb` runs `lighttpd` as the active user. I definitely have full permissions to the repository.

Comment: Well, I have a similar issue on my website
https://www.american-data.com/pub works ok
and 
http://www.american-data.com/pub gives the 403 Error
I was getting that for a few reasons, problems following symlinks, and .htaccess files and problems with httpd.conf to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

check the git-web cgi (the perl), see the directory of the projectroot is same as your currect setting. there are some settings that not in gitweb.conf

Answer (score 1):

Two years later ..

I fixed this problem by stating the projectroot in gitweb.cgi (it's the only value that seems to matter)

Answer (score 0):

And another year later ...

I fixed this problem (F12, git 1.7.2.3) by:

```
vi .git/gitweb/gitweb.cgi   # set DocumentRoot to <root>/.git/gitweb.cgi
GITWEB_CONFIG=.git/gitweb lighttpd -f .git/gitweb/httpd.conf
```

I didn't dig further  to figure out why I needed to do this ...

Answer (score 0):

two year later ...

I fixed this problem by adding this line

```
Options All ExecCGI FollowSymLinks Includes Indexes
```

to my httpd.conf file