# gitosis did not generate projects.list automatically, gitweb can't work

Tags: git, gitosis

I setup a `gitosis` managed git server.

`git clone` is ok.

but when I set `gitweb` via `gitweb.conf` as below:

---

```
$projectroot = "/srv/gitosis/repositories";

$git_temp = "/tmp";

$home_text = "indextext.html";

$projects_list = "/srv/gitosis/gitosis/projects.list";

$stylesheet = "/gitweb/gitweb.css";

$logo = "/gitweb/git-logo.png";

$favicon = "/gitweb/git-favicon.png";
```

---

Btw, the commet was deleted because of the special symbol # is using as bold prefix.

"`403 Forbidden - No projects found`" is reported when I access gitweb through "http://localhost/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi"

I checked the projects.list file it is empty, is that the reason why gitweb access failed?
what would be the correct content? can i add it manually?

Comment: intersted in a answer as well, same problem here

Answer (score 3):

You need this in your gitosis.conf for every project you want to publish via gitweb:

```
[repo myreponame]
gitweb = yes
```

optionally also add `owner` and `description`.

You can find more info in gitosis' [documentation](http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git;a=blob;f=README.rst), linked from the [author's website](http://eagain.net/blog/2007/10/12/snakepit-and-gitosis.html).

Answer (score 0):

Is this similar to "[git instaweb gives 403 Forbidden - No projects found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112613/git-instaweb-gives-403-forbidden-no-projects-found) ", where you need to remove the `$projectroot` line from `/etc/gitweb.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

What did you set gitweb = yes in the gitosis.conf file for the repo?

Answer (score 0):

I created a blog post recently about [getting gitosis and gitweb to play nice together](http://robertmassaioli.wordpress.com/2010/04/09/gitweb-and-gitosis-play-nice/) because I had the exact same problem and I wanted to let others know how to get it working too. Take a look and read through it and you should end up with a setup that just works. And if you have questions then feel free to ask.

I hope that this helps.